# Why does Charles give error code for SSL Proxy?

Tags: http-proxy

I have a local nginx proxy that is letting my local site work on `https://fakedomain.com/endpoint`. If I hit it in the browser, Charles shows the response properly.

[image: Shows HTML]

If I use the SSL Proxy such that hitting `https://www.anotherdomain.com/endpoint` points at `https://fakedomain.com/endpoint`, it gives a Response Code of -1 with a response preview that looks like this:

[image: Bad response]

I have SSL Proxying working fine, generally. If I proxy to a known `https` location, Charles proxy works fine.

[image: Facebook to Yahoo]

My local site/server uses a `.crt` and `.key` file that someone else generated, which I think may be the problem. I'm on a Mac, double clicked the `.crt`, and got it added to my keychain. I opened it up and set it to always trust:[image: always trust]

My guess is that Charles doesn't trust this cert when proxying, so it errors out. Just not sure how to fix this.

*Note: I was redirected to this exchange from Networking stack*

Answer (score 0):

URL A redirects to URL B. I had my proxy set as A -> C. I changed my proxy from B -> C and it worked. Weird.